# How is $-6$ dB pressure amplitude is the same as FWHM?

Tags: sound, ultrasound

I keep reading many literature, and in most cases $-6$ dB is referenced as the [full width at half maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) (FWHM). Mathematically, how is that possible from the definition of dB?

Answer (score 2):

$$20\log_{10}\left(\frac12\right)=-6.0206$$

Comment: Would you please explain? I did find the pressure ratio too. But I do not understand how it is FWHM like in Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @KatherinRomanova: -6 dB is half maximum, so between the two -6 dB points you have FWHM (assuming uni-modality like in a Gaussian distribution).